# List comprehension and dealing with an empty list; list of lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am attempting to perform a list comprehension. I want to check the values in a smaller list with the values of the larger list. I think my code works. That is until one of my inner lists is empty.

The logic makes sense... there is no element at position 0 of the smaller list therefore index error:

```
['w', 'c']
    if x[0] != y[0]:
['w', 'c']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

However, what I want to know is what is the proper way to write this s/t it won't error here and instead just assume there was no match and move on to the next list within list_one?

Here is my code:

```
a = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['w', 'c'], []]
b = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'f', 'g'], ['x', 'y', 'z']]


def check_contents(list_one, list_two):

  if len(list_one)<=len(list_two):
    for x in list_one:
      for y in list_two:
        if x[0] != y[0]:
          print(x)
  else:
    for x in list_two:
      for y in list_one:
        if x[0] != y[0]:
          print(x)


check_contents(a, b)
```

Comment: You could use a try except block

Comment: @Agile_Eagle While that is a good idea and it is probably how I would do it in say Java I was hoping someone might be aware of some library or other Pythonic method of doing this that would be short and sweet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your two loops do the same thing. DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). Second, to see if a list is empty, check its truth value. Empty lists evaluate to `False`.

```
def check_contents(list_one, list_two):
    shorter, longer = sorted([list_one, list_two], key = len)
    for x in longer:
        if not x:
            continue
        for y in shorter:
            if not y:
                continue
            if x[0] != y[0]:
                print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for x, y in zip(list_one, list_two):
    if x and y and x[0] != y[0]:
        print(x)
    else:
        # Rest of the code here
```

Using the `zip()` function creates a `zip` object so that you can iterate through both `list-one` and `list-two` at the same time, comparing their elements. This takes care of your empty list problem as well.

Comment: Is this checking the first element of the first list within the smaller list and comparing it with the first element of the first list within the larger list to determine if they are equal? That is the logic I need.

Comment: Yes. (Since I need a minimum of 15 characters to comment, I am including this sentence in my comment)

Comment: You shouldn't. You can check the truth values of `x` and `y` with `if x and y`

Answer (score 1):

You can change your conditional to this:

```
if x and x[0] != y[0]:
```

Empty lists are falsy, and non-empty lists are truthy, thus this only evaluates `x[0] != y[0]` if x is non empty (i.e. `x[0]` exists).